# Move Ball left and right with mouse drag Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball that have a continuous bouncing, and I want to move it left and right in the x Axis with the mouse, so it follow the mouse's X movement.

I made the script bellow, but the ball didn't move with mouse!

**Ball Script:**

```
private Vector3 pos;
public Camera cam;

public Rigidbody Ball;
public float Speed;
public static float GlobalGravity = -9.8f;
public float GravityScale = 1.0f;
bool isforce = false;

private void Start(){

    Ball = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Ball.useGravity = false;

}


private void FixedUpdate(){

    Vector3 gravity = GlobalGravity * GravityScale * Vector3.up;
    Ball.AddForce(gravity, ForceMode.Acceleration);

}

void force (){

    isforce = false;
    Ball.AddForce(Vector3.up * Speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}

private void Update(){

    if (isforce == true){

        force();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){

        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 wantedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, transform.position.y, 10));
        transform.position = wantedPos;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    isforce = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know what happens. yours was set to right click, but i changed this one to left click, other than that i just sat the balls x to the raw x of the mouse input.

```
private void Update(){

    if (isforce == true){

        force();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){

        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 wantedPos = transform.position;
wantedPos.x=Input.mousePosition.x;
        transform.position = wantedPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: When clicking the ball fall far from the screen, and the X position become 511 instead of 0 !

Comment: try it with your original code and right click and see if it works for you

Comment: I tried it, but it changed its Y position, and also the ball stop from bouncing when dragging

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you use transform.position, the Unity Physics will no apply to the rigidBody. Find your mouse position relative to the ball and add Force in the X direction accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on what it is you want.

Also as @Hamed answered, when using physics you don't want to update the transform directly but add force using the Rigidbody.

**Force Constant relative to where the Mouse is**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Vector2 force = Vector2.zero;

    //Get the Balls current screenX position
    float ballX = Camera.WorldToScreenPoint(Ball.transform.position).x;

    //Check if Click was Left or Right of the Ball
    if (ballX > Input.mousePosition.x)
    {
        //Click was Left of the Ball
        force = new Vector2(-1f, 0f);
    }
    else if (ballX < Input.mousePosition.x)
    {
        //Click was Right of the Ball
        force = new Vector2(1f, 0f);
    }

    //Adjust force amount to your suiting
    Ball.Addforce(force * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**Force relative to the mouse movement**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Vector2 force = Vector2.zero;

    float mouseDelta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    //Check if the Mouse is going Left or Right
    if (mouseDelta < 0f)
    {
        //Click was Left of the Ball
        force = new Vector2(-1f, 0f);
    }
    else if (mouseDelta > 0f)
    {
        //Click was Right of the Ball
        force = new Vector2(1f, 0f);
    }

    // Update force relative to mouse movement
    force = Mathf.Abs(mouseDelta) * force;

    //Adjust force amount to your suiting
    Ball.Addforce(force * Time.deltaTime)
}
```

*Hastily written, look then write your own :)*