# Problem in moving object by mouse dragging Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball moving forward, and to move it right and left (by mouse dragging), I want to click anywhere on the screen and than use the difference between the object X axis value and the initial mouse position X axis value.

The problem I have with this script is when clicking, the ball move quickly to the Mouse position and then start moving with the mouse movement, so it didn't use the difference as I said before.

```
private float distance;
Vector3 initialPosition;

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.MousePosition));
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0)
        {

               Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
               Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
               Ball.MovePosition(new Vector3(rayPoint.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));

        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of opening new questions trying to solve the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906254/move-ball-left-and-right-with-mouse-drag-unity-3d) you should try to stick with that one and wait until you have your problem solved

Comment: @derHugo Yes but it's not the same problem, here the only issue I have is to move object by difference between mouse position and ball position.